# WooCommerce using meta_query to get products where custom checkbox option is NOT checked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-query

I have built a WooCommerce website for a client with a "Latest Products" page.  Due to the competitive nature of the client's industry, the client wants to be able to select certain products to NOT appear amongst the Latest Products.

For this, I have added a custom "Hide from Latest Products" checkbox to the product editor with this code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'gd_add_product_extra_options_metabox');
function gd_add_product_extra_options_metabox(){
    add_meta_box("product_extra_options_meta", "Extra Options", "gd_product_extra_options_metabox", "product", "side", "high");
}

// ADD CUSTOM FIELDS //
function gd_product_extra_options_metabox(){
global $post;
    // Nonce field to validate form request came from current site
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_fields' );
    // Get the field data if it's already been entered
$hide_from_latest = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hide_from_latest', true );
if($hide_from_latest == '1'){$checked = ' checked';}else{$checked = '';}
    // Output the field
echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="hide_from_latest" value="1"' . $checked . '> Hide from Latest Products</p>';
}
```

And so on and so forth with the saving code, etc.  The checkbox appears to work perfectly.

The problem though, is in writing a custom product query to fetch all of the latest products for which this checkbox is NOT checked.

For testing, I have checked and saved the "Hide" option for only 1 product.
I have my query as follows:

```
$products = new WP_Query( array (
'post_type'         => 'product',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'    => '100',
'order_by'          => 'date',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'hide_from_latest',
        'value'     => '1',
        'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE'
    ),
)
```

This gives me a very empty screen with "There is no results."

If, however, I change the meta_query to:

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'hide_from_latest',
        'value'     => '1',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
)
```

Then it fetches and displays the 1 single product that I have checked and saved the option for.

I have tried various other options such as using "=" and "!=" for 'compare', I've tried changing the value of the checkbox to "on" and then having 'value' => 'on' in the meta_query, etc.  The results are always the same.

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT:

Here is my full code:

```
    // ADD CUSTOM OPTIONS TO WOOCOMMERCE PRODUCTS //
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'gd_add_product_extra_options_metabox');
function gd_add_product_extra_options_metabox(){
    add_meta_box("product_extra_options_meta", "Extra Options", "gd_product_extra_options_metabox", "product", "side", "high");
}

// ADD CUSTOM FIELDS //
function gd_product_extra_options_metabox(){
global $post;
    // Nonce field to validate form request came from current site
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'notice_fields' );
    // Get the field data if it's already been entered
$hide_from_latest = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hide_from_latest', true );
if($hide_from_latest == '1'){$checked = ' checked';}else{$checked = '';}
    // Output the field
echo '<p><input type="checkbox" name="hide_from_latest" value="1"' . $checked . '> Hide from Latest Products</p>';
}

// SAVE METABOX DATA //
function gd_save_product_extra_options_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Return if the user doesn't have edit permissions.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times.
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['notice_fields'], basename(__FILE__)) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // Now that we're authenticated, time to save the data.
    // This sanitizes the data from the field and saves it into an array $product_meta.
    $product_meta['hide_from_latest'] = esc_textarea( $_POST['hide_from_latest'] );
    // Cycle through the $notice_meta array.
    foreach ( $product_meta as $key => $value ) :
        // Don't store custom data twice
        if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
            // If the custom field already has a value, update it.
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        } else {
            // If the custom field doesn't have a value, add it.
            add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
        }
        if ( ! $value ) {
            // Delete the meta key if there's no value
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
        }
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'gd_save_product_extra_options_metabox', 1, 2 );




if( ! function_exists('latest_products_censored') ) {

    // Add Shortcode
    function latest_products_censored( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        // Attributes 
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'columns'   => '4',
                'limit'     => '100'
            ),
            $atts, 'products_test'
        );


        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        // The WP_Query
        $products = new WP_Query( array (
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'    => $atts['limit'],
            'order_by'          => 'date',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'meta_query'        => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'hide_from_latest',
                    'value'     => '1',
                    'compare'   => 'NOT LIKE'
                ),
            )
        ));

        ob_start();

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();     ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php
        } else {
            do_action( "woocommerce_shortcode_products_loop_no_results", $atts     );
            echo "<p>There is no results.</p>";
        }

        woocommerce_reset_loop();
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    add_shortcode( 'latest_products_censored', 'latest_products_censored' );
}
```

Comment: Your custom metabox checkout field, is not saved actually to the product.

Comment: It should be.  Sorry, perhaps I need to include my full code here so you can see everything.  I'll add it in the main post above.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging in the Wordpress Codex, I have found the answer!

The meta_query needs to be:

```
'meta_query'        => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'hide_from_latest',
        'value'     => '1',
        'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
    ),
)
```

I have just given that a go and it is now working perfectly!  :-)